# Adding Data into my database C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm getting an error when trying to add data to my database. *Look further down for more detail.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
            row[1] = regname.Text;
            row[2] = regpass.Text;
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);

            try
            {
                objConnect.UpdateDatabase(ds);
                MaxRows = MaxRows + 1;
                inc = MaxRows - 1;
                MessageBox.Show("Database updated");
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            }
        }
```

My method to update database:

```
public void UpdateDatabase(System.Data.DataSet ds)
        {
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder cb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(da_1);
            cb.DataAdapter.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
}
```

The line :

```
DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
```

in particular `.NewRow();`

throws an error when run:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in AllIn1Database.exe

I'm following this tutorial [C# Adding to databases](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s12p9.html)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm following the same tutorial and I'm also stuck at the same part, would love some help. The issue seems to be something to do with the DataAdapter in the DatabaseConnection class. The error I get is "The name 'da_1' does not exist in the current context:

```
 public System.Data.DataSet MyDataSet()
{
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(strCon);

    con.Open();

    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da_1  = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql_string, con);

    System.Data.DataSet dat_set = new System.Data.DataSet();
    da_1.Fill(dat_set, "Table_Data_1");
    con.Close();

    return dat_set;
}

public void UpdateDatabase(System.Data.DataSet ds)
{
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder cb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(da_1);

    cb.DataAdapter.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
```

I managed to resolve this issue by adding at the top of my DatabaseConnection class

```
public static System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da_1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Method you did not create an object "ds". So the Null Reference Exception occurs because you are trying to run a method on a non-object (null).

Please read the previous parts of the tutorial. This one explains where "ds" comes from:
http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s12p7.html

Comment: And if `ds` is declared at outter scope?

Comment: That did absolutely nothing. The error now says 'Cannot instantiate Object, as well as the previous error before.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** it is because you have created the coumns for created `Row` from the `index 1` but but row column starts from `index 0`.

**Solution :**  you need to created the `row` columns from `index 0`.

Try This:

```
DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
row[0] = regname.Text;
row[1] = regpass.Text;
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: Unfortuunatley that didn't work. I didn't expect it to because row[0] relates to the ID of the database registry.